# Failed to convert webm audio file to mp4 using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, webm

I have a webm audio file , I was trying to convert it into mp4 using ffmpeg. But it is failed to create the mp4. The info about the file is as follows.

```
fmpeg -i 54ebe077-96fc-4ace-9a38-f13c58807322.webm -hide_banner

Input #0, matroska,webm, from '54ebe077-96fc-4ace-9a38-f13c58807322.webm':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf56.40.101
    creation_time   : 2019-10-22T11:19:12.000000Z
  Duration: 00:00:24.16, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 41 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: vp8, yuv420p, 640x480, SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 1k tbc (default)
    Stream #0:1: Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, mono, fltp (default)
At least one output file must be specifiedffmpeg -i  54ebe077-96fc-4ace-9a38-f13c58807322.webm -qscale 0 out.mp4
```

I was tried to convert it using the following command

```
ffmpeg -i  54ebe077-96fc-4ace-9a38-f13c58807322.webm -qscale 0 out.mp4
```

It throws errors

```
[opus @ 0x56489c7f9840] LBRR frames is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
[opus @ 0x56489c7f9840] Error decoding a SILK frame.
[opus @ 0x56489c7f9840] Error decoding an Opus frame.
Too many packets buffered for output stream 0:1.
[aac @ 0x56489c82d640] Qavg: 59180.625
[aac @ 0x56489c82d640] 2 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

How to fix this issue? I have played the file in VLC and I can hear the sound from the source file. But failed to convert it

Answer (score 2):

## Your `ffmpeg` is too old

Update your `ffmpeg`:

- [Download an already compiled `ffmpeg`](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html)
- Or see [compile instructions at FFmpeg Wiki](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide)

This was ticket [#4641: Error decoding SILK frame](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4641). The fix is newer than the most current release branch (FFmpeg 4.3 as of writing this), so you have to get a build from the git master branch (either of the links above will do), or wait for FFmpeg 4.4.

## If you can't update

If you can't update your `ffmpeg` the old workaround is to use libopus to decode:

```
ffmpeg -c:a libopus -i input ...
```

Comment: It is not working and i ogt it working using ffmpeg -acodec libopus -i 54ebe077-96fc-4ace-9a38-f13c58807322.webm -max_muxing_queue_size 9999 -strict experimental -movflags faststart foo.mp4

Comment: No need for `-strict experimental`. What error did you get when you tried my example? "Not working" is not descriptive.