# FFMpeg; Error when mixing two audio stream

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg

I'm recording two stream by ffmpeg with this command:

```
ffmpeg -protocol_whitelist pipe,udp,rtp -fflags +genpts -f sdp -i pipe:0 \
-map 0:v:0 -c:v copy \
-filter_complex \
"[0:a:0]volume=0.5[a0]; \
 [0:a:1]volume=0.5[a1]; \
 [a0][a1]amerge=inputs=2,pan=stereo|c0<c0+c2|c1<c1+c3[out]" \
-map [out] -c:a libopus \
-flags +global_header out.webm
```

that `[0:v:0]` is my video stream and `[0:a:0]` and `[0:a:1]` are my audio streams that I want to mix them up and record it associate with video stream.

But unfortunately, I get this ugly error sometimes that it causes silence in final video. I mean, when I get this error my final video becomes silence.

> LBRR frames is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the
> newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your
> file has a feature which has not been implemented.
>
> Error decoding a SILK frame.
>
> Error decoding an Opus frame.

My ffmpeg version is:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Duplicate of [Failed to convert webm audio file to mp4 using FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58504102/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your `ffmpeg`. Apparently you installed it by default in ubuntu like this:

```
apt-get install ffmpeg
```

that installs the version you mentioned.
You can install it from git repo like this:

```
apt-get install libvorbis-dev
apt-get install libvpx-dev
git clone https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --extra-cflags=-I/opt/local/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/local/lib --enable-nonfree --enable-libvpx --enable-libvorbis
make
make install
```

You can test it when you installed by this:

```
./ffmpeg
```

Please pay attention that you can't run `ffmpeg` like before. You have to address that to `/root/ffmpeg/ffmpeg`.

Comment: Easier method is to [download an already compiled ffmpeg](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) or see [FFmpeg Wiki: Compile and Install on Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) for instructions that will include libopus. No need for `--enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree` if you're only enabling libvpx and libvorbis.